# pnpm update vs nx migrate are giving different results

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx, pnpm

I want to use nx's migrate feature to maintain & update the package.json dependencies.

I use pnpm as my node package manager.

When running `pnpm update`, pnpm lists us all the outdated packages and updates them:

```
Packages: +80 -100
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++------------------------------------------------------------------

dependencies:
- @sentry/nextjs 7.61.1
+ @sentry/nextjs 7.64.0
- @sentry/node 7.61.1
+ @sentry/node 7.64.0
- @sentry/utils 7.61.1
+ @sentry/utils 7.64.0
- next-auth 4.22.5
+ next-auth 4.23.0
- zod 3.21.4
+ zod 3.22.0

devDependencies:
- @commitlint/cli 17.6.7
+ @commitlint/cli 17.7.1
- @commitlint/config-conventional 17.6.7
+ @commitlint/config-conventional 17.7.0
- @swc/jest 0.2.28
+ @swc/jest 0.2.29
- autoprefixer 10.4.14
+ autoprefixer 10.4.15
```

When running `nx migrate latest`, there aren't any results, besides the following:

```
> nx migrate latest     
Fetching meta data about packages.
It may take a few minutes.
Fetching nx@16.6.0
Fetching nx@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/cypress@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/next@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/workspace@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/react@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/jest@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/linter@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/js@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/eslint-plugin@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/cypress@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/next@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/jest@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/workspace@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/linter@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/react@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/eslint-plugin@16.6.0
Fetching @nx/js@16.6.0

 >  NX   The migrate command has run successfully.

   - package.json has been updated.
   - There are no migrations to run, so migrations.json has not been created.


 >  NX   Next steps:

   - Make sure package.json changes make sense and then run 'pnpm install --no-frozen-lockfile',
   - To learn more go to https://nx.dev/core-features/automate-updating-dependencies
```

Is that normal? Or am I misunderstanding the `migrate` feature?

TIA